# calculate an object property based on the value of another property of the same object

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the value of "name" inside on the obj object. How can I find it without function invocation?

I wanna use just `obj.isActive` not `obj.isActive()`

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: function () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

// and after a while I need to check if is active:

console.log(obj);

// { 
//   name: 'X Æ A-12 Musk',
//   isActive: [Function: isActive]  <--------- NOT COOL ! 
// }
```

---

If use an IFEE:

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: (function () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  })(),
};
```

I get:

```
return this.name.length > 4;
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Comment: use a class with a getter.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Or an object with a getter

Comment: I cannot add more properties to that object, not can I use an outside class, I have a library that it takes that object and has to isActive as a string. not a function. The only thing I can do is to provide a value: true of false to it

Comment: @aldobsom so why can't you make it with a getter? `get isActive { return ... }`

Comment: @epascarello I cannot use other new properties inside that object. The library that I'm using is not aware of any other properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to have to call isActive as a function, you can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
const obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  get isActive () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

console.log(obj.isActive);
```

Comment: yes this works and seems like the easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question why you can do an IIFE but not a getter, but here are some other potential workarounds.

**1. Use a Proxy to intercept the property accessor:**

If you can't modify the object itself you could wrap it in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), and pass the proxy to the library.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: function () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'isActive') {
      return target?.isActive?.();
    }
    return target[prop]
  }
});

console.log(proxy.isActive); // true
console.log(proxy.name); // "X Æ A-12 Musk"
console.log(proxy);
/*
{
  "name": "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  "isActive": true
}
*/
```

This could be generalized to invoke any getter function if it's present on the target:

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: function () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop) {
    const x = target[prop];
    return typeof x === 'function' ? target[prop]() : x;
  }
});

console.log(proxy.isActive); // true
console.log(proxy.name); // "X Æ A-12 Musk"
console.log(proxy);
/*
{
  "name": "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  "isActive": true
}
*/
```

Note: I'm invoking `target[prop]()` instead of `x()` here because invoking the disassociated function `x()` has scope implications that could produce errors or unexpected results.(The same issue that makes your IIFE blow up.)

**2. Use `Object.defineProperty` to establish the getter.**

Again, it's not clear to me why you can't put a getter on the object literal directly, so I don't know if this is viable either.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: function() {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "isActive", {
  get() {
    return this.name.length > 4
  }
})

console.log(obj);
/*
{
  "name": "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  "isActive": true
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to ray's answer, what about something like this:

```js
let obj = {
    name: "test"
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "isActive", {
    get: function() {
        return obj.name.length > 3;
    }
});

console.log(obj.isActive); // Output: true
```

If it helps, and you were to use it constantly, you could create a helper function:

```js
   
function defineIsActive(object, condition) {
    
    Object.defineProperty(obj, "isActive", {
        get: function() {
            return condition
        }
    });
}

let obj = {
  name: 'test'
}

// And simply use it like so:
defineIsActive(obj, obj.name.length > 3)

console.log(obj.isActive)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot add more properties to that object

You can create wrapper object prototyped by the original object, and define getter in the former.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "X Æ A-12 Musk",
  isActive: function () {
    return this.name.length > 4;
  },
};

function makeWrapper (obj) {
  let wrapper = Object.create(obj);
  Object.defineProperty(wrapper, 'isActive', {
    get () { return obj.isActive(); },
    enumerable: true
  });
  return wrapper;
}

let obj2 = makeWrapper(obj);
console.log(obj2);
```